# Android map overlay with sprites pathfinding

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to make an Android App, with a real map and a overlay for the map, where sprites are drawn (can be dots or small images).

This is a rather hard question, so I have made a sketch of a map of a small city, where only roads and streets can be seen. That might look something like this on the device:

[image]

Imagine the red dots to be bots, and they want to get to the yellow dot, assuming they know the position.

What Android Map API should I use to be able to:

1. Draw custom sprites on a given location on the map (geo-coordinates rather than screen coordinates).
2. Generate valid paths from the streets and roads on the map, which the dots can move on (black lines).
3. Use pathfinding to calculate the shortest routes, e.g. from red dot to yellow dot.
4. Must be able to draw more than 10 sprites on the map.

*(the map doesn't have to support 3d views or street views. Plain old top-down view is just fine)*

If no map API exists that does not meet these requirements, what are some other solutions?

I'm really excited about this project, but I'm having a lot of trouble getting started with it, so any help or guidance will be much appreciated.

**EDIT:
It seems that there is no answer to my question. I will leave this open and report back with my own solution.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/index) and `Marker` class.
2. All valid paths? You probably should not need it if you use Android API v2 with real map drawn for you, but you can also try to use Google Directions API.
3. [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/).
4. No API exist that can handle more than 10 objects. You probably need something from NASA.

Have fun coding.

Comment: Thanks. I'll work on it and see if I can get around the 10 object restriction. 
Will report back

Comment: @Janman That was a joke. You can have hundreds of markers with API v2 without any problems.

Comment: I see.
Haven't really gotten into the API v2 yet :)